# ¿Como enviar un arreglo a la vista de correo electrónico con laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente metodo en un controlador para enviar correo electronico con laravel.

```
 public function EnviarComentario()
    {
        try
        {
           $data = [
                    'correo' => 'prueba',
                    'nombre' => 'Prueba',
                    'comentario' => 'Esto es una prueba de comentario'
           ];

           Mail::send('mails.ComentariosParqueos', $data, function ($message){
                $message->subject('Comentario');
                $message->to('parqueosumg@gmail.com');
            });

            $statusCode     = 200;
            $this->message  = "Correo enviado correctamente";
            $this->result   = true;
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            $statusCode     = 200;
            $this->message  = $e->getMessage();
        }
        finally
        {
            $response =
            [
                'message'   => $this->message,
                'result'    => $this->result
            ];
                return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
        }
    }
```

El correo lo envia correctamente solo que cuando intento pasar $data para mostrar los valores que contiene no envia nada.

esta es la ruta:

```
Route::any('comentario','ParqueosController@EnviarComentario');
```

y la vista es la siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Prueba de correo {{$data["correo"]}} </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿A qué vista envía el `array` ?  ¿Por qué  en formato `json` ? ¿ Está enviando por `ajax`? ¿Por qué no simplemente un `with` a la vista o un `compact`

Comment: ¿Como sugiere realizarlo entonces?.
En formato json solo es la respuesta, no es lo que envio en si el arreglo que debo enviar es $data, y mostrarlo en el html que esta hasta abajo.

Comment: Sé que es la respuesta , y sé lo que envía en el correo. Preguntaba si el envió lo hacía mediante `ajax` o algo así. Sí solo desea mostrar un mensaje de acuerdo al estado del envió . podría usar `flash` de `session`

Comment: Mediante angularjs http, pero ando realizando eso solo como prueba de ver si envia el arreglo.

Comment: la vista se llama ComentariosParqueos

Answer (score 0):

Sí lo que desea enviar una respuesta de acuerdo al estado del `email` , es decir si se envió o no , podría emplear [session()->flash()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data)

```
public function EnviarComentario()
{
    try
    {
        /* Envio del Email */
        $this->message  = "Correo enviado correctamente";
        $this->result   = true;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $this->result     = false;
        $this->message  = 'No se pudo enviar el Correo';
    }
    if($this->result){
        session()->flash('success',$this->message);
    }
    else{
        session()->flash('error',$this->message);
    }

    return redirect()->route('nombrerutaaredirigir');
}
```

En su vista recogería estos valores de `flash`, para esto podría emplear [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) o simplemente imprimir el `HTML` que desee.

```
@if (session()->has('success'))
  <script>
    toastr.success("{{ Session::get('success')}}");
  </script>
  {{--O --}}
  <div class="alert alert-info">
    {{Session::get('success')}}
  </div>
@elseif(session()->has('error'))
  <script>
    toastr.warning("{{ Session::get('error')}}");
  </script>
  {{--O --}}
  <div  class="alert alert-danger">
    {{Session::get('error')}}
  </div>
@endif
```